# Android variable to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android

I am building an Android WebView which loads an url on a server of mine. However, now I want to use an identifier from the Android as parameter of a function on the JS code and I simply can't do it.

I already tried appending "javascript:myFunction(myParameter);" to the url on the loadUrl method and tried adding a JavascriptInterface. Neither of them did work, and it looked like it needed my files (html and js) to be local. However, I need to open a xml document and, as far as I know, you can't do it with local files, so I couldn't test it.

I am not used to web/android dev, so I don't even know if I'm not trying to do something dumb, but it seems to me that it should be simple to do and yet I'm stuck on it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the variable to the URL, for example:

```
file://my/file.html?variable=someValue
```

You should then be able to parse the URL in JS using [`document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location), for example:

```
alert(document.location);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!